# Mute toggle on multiple audio playing at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm trying to make an A/B test comparison for audio.  It will be a "demo" version of a song and a real version.

I have them playing and stopping at the same time, but i can't work out the mute toggle.  (i have it as two buttons now, but ideally i'd love to have one button that will mute one audio and unmute the other, and vice versa on reclick.  Sorry i'm still learning js so any help would be awesome!)

I have what i have so far in a jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/nickdulac/36r22svz/

html

```
    <audio id="audio1" muted controls>
    <source src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1538714/article_resources/cat.m4a" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <source src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1538714/article_resources/cat.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio><br />
<audio id="audio2" controls>
    <source src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1538714/article_resources/song.m4a" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <source src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1538714/article_resources/song.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio><br />
<button onclick="play();">Play</button><br />
<button onclick="stop();">Stop</button><br />
<button onclick="mute1();">Mute 1</button><br />
<button onclick="mute2();">Mute 2</button><br />
```

js

```
var play = function() {
    var audio1 = document.getElementById('audio1');
    var audio2 = document.getElementById('audio2');
    audio1.play(); 
    audio2.play(); 
}
var stop = function() {
    var audio1 = document.getElementById('audio1');
    var audio2 = document.getElementById('audio2');
    audio1.pause();
    audio2.pause(); 
}
var mute1 = function() {
    var audio1 = document.getElementById('audio1');
    var audio2 = document.getElementById('audio2');
    audio1.volume() = 1; 
    audio2.volume() = 0; 
}

var mute2 = function() {
    var audio1 = document.getElementById('audio1');
    var audio2 = document.getElementById('audio2');
    audio1.volume() = 0; 
    audio2.volume() = 1; 
}
```

p.s. i have random audio in there for now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply have a global variable. a flag that knows the current status and work accordingly. (ADDED MUTE)

Two different Mute buttons
Please check this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/36r22svz/6/

Single Mute Toggle
Please check this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/36r22svz/7/

HTML

```
<audio id="audio1" controls>
    <source src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1538714/article_resources/cat.m4a" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <source src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1538714/article_resources/cat.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio><br />
<audio id="audio2" controls>
    <source src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1538714/article_resources/song.m4a" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <source src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1538714/article_resources/song.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio><br />
<button onclick="play();" id="button1">Play</button><br />
<button onclick="mute();" id="button2">Mute</button><br />
```

JS

```
var audio1 = document.getElementById('audio1');
var audio2 = document.getElementById('audio2');
var button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
var isPlaying = false;
var muteToggle = true;
var play = function() {
    if(!isPlaying){
      button1.innerHTML = 'Pause';
      audio1.play(); // this stream will immediately stop when the next line is run on iOS
        audio2.play(); // this will stop audio1 on iOS
      isPlaying = true;
    } else {
      button1.innerHTML = 'Play';
      audio1.pause(); // this stream will immediately stop when the next line is run on iOS
        audio2.pause(); // this will stop audio1 on iOS
      isPlaying = false;
    }
}
var mute = function(){
  if(muteToggle){
      muteToggle = false;
    audio1.muted = true;
    audio2.muted = false;
  } else {
      muteToggle = true;
    audio2.muted = true;
    audio1.muted = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry maybe i wasn't clear, i WANT them to be playing at the same time, i just want to be able to mute one and unmute the other so that the comparison between the two audio files can be heard!

Comment: Got it, updating the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think adding this (very simple) funtion and calling to it from one button it should work.

Add this to your Javascript

```
var muted = 'on';
var button = document.getElementById(mutebut);
function muteorplay(){
if (muted == 'on'){
mute1()
muted='off';
button.innerHTML='Mute 1';
}else{
mute2()
muted='on';
button.innerHTML='Mute 2';
}
}
```

And replace the two mute buttons with this one

```
<button onclick="muteorplay();" id="mutebut">Mute 2</button><br />
```